# count frequency of all items in tsql

Tags: t-sql, frequency

Suppose I have a table, like so:

`````````````````````
UserID    Meh    Meh //meh is some column
````````````````````
01        ...    ...
01        ...    ...
03        ...    ...
05        ...    ...
05        ...    ...
01        ...    ...
03        ...    ...
`````````````````````

So I want to count how many times each userid appears in this table. I am doing this now:

```
select UserId from NinjaTable group by UserId
```

but its giving me something that I dont know or understand.
I want the result to be like so:

````````````````````
UserID    Frequency
```````````````````
01        3
03        2
05        2
````````````````````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are almost there.

You are grouping correctly, just add the count to select clause.

```
select UserId, COUNT(*) from NinjaTable group by UserId order by COUNT(*) desc
```

that should do it really.

edit: thanks to @abe for pointing the order.

Comment: Shouldn't it be desc instead of asc?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
select UserId, count(*) as Frequency from NinjaTable group by UserId
```

Tack on an `order by UserId` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select UserID, Count(*) 
from theTable 
group by UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to use is the `COUNT` function:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) AS Frequency FROM NinjaTable GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the group by statement:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(1) FROM MyTable GROUP BY UserId ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

This would group all the user Ids, find the count of rows (the frequency for you), and then sort the result set by the frequency descending.